# Erro ao tentar criar uma credencial de login para chromium usando Angular

Tags: angular, chromium

Boa tarde pessoal, sou novo aqui na comunidade. Estou fazendo uma migração de framework angularjs para angular, e me deparei com um erro que não estou conseguindo solução.
Anteriormente no angularjs havia um sistema de login que usava as credenciais do google chrome para gerar o login automático através de um checkbox, ao marcar ele geraria as credenciais. O código era basicamente esse:

```
if ('credentials' in navigator) {
  navigator.credentials.get({password:true}).then((auth) => {
    if (auth !== null) {
      this.login.conta = auth.name;
      this.login.email = auth.id;
      this.login.senha = auth.password;
      this.post();
    }
  });
}
```

Mas está gerando o seguinte erro:

```
Argument of type '{ password: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'password' does not exist in type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.
```

Já tentei de tudo, pesquisei possíveis soluções e até agora nada deu certo. Cheguei a instalar algumas bibliotecas sugeridas em outros posts mas não resolvou.
Se alguém tiver uma solução, serei muito grato.
Att.

Comment: parece que não esta levando em consideração quando "credentials" não estiver presente no "navigator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, a solução para minha questão foi criar um arquivos JS.
Criei uma função com o código:

```
navigator.credentials.get({ password: true }).then(function (auth) {
    if (auth !== null) {
        this.login.conta = auth.name;
        this.login.email = auth.id;
        this.login.senha = auth.password;
    }
});
```

E fiz a referencia no angular.json

```
"build": {
   ......
"options": {
    .......
    "scripts": [
        "src/assets/js/nomedoarquivo.js"
    ]
},
```

Declarei a função no meu componente:

```
declare function authCredentials(): void;
```

E com isso funcionou como esperado.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe para acessar as credenciais do usuário no Angular é ligeiramente diferente do AngularJS, mas a lógica geral é a mesma. Aqui está como essa verificação deveria ser escrita no Angular:

```
import { CredentialsContainer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

if ('credentials' in navigator) {
    navigator.credentials.get({password:true}).then((creds: CredentialsContainer) => {
        if (auth !== null) {
            this.login.conta = auth.name;
            this.login.email = auth.id;
            this.login.senha = auth.password;
            this.post();
        }
    });
}
```

Editei a resposta e acredito que deve resolver o problema. Mas em tese, a linha **"import { Credentials } from '@angular/compiler';"** está tentando importar uma classe "Credentials" de um módulo que não existe na biblioteca "@angular/compiler". Isso está causando um erro de compilação. É importante informar qual versão do angular vc está trabalhando.

**Era só um exemplo de importação de credenciais.**

A classe 'Credentials' não é uma classe padrão do javascript, e sim uma classe específica para **WebAuthn**. Assim, você precisaria importar a classe 'Credentials' de uma biblioteca específica para **WebAuthn**.

Em relação ao erro "Argument of type '{ password: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CredentialRequestOptions'", você está passando um objeto com uma propriedade "password: true" para o método "navigator.credentials.get()", mas este método espera receber um objeto do tipo 'CredentialRequestOptions' que tem uma estrutura diferente.

Deve ser algo como:

```
navigator.credentials.get({
    publicKey: {
        challenge: new Uint8Array(challenge),
        timeout: 60000,
        rpId: "example.com",
        allowCredentials: [{
            type: "public-key",
            id: new Uint8Array(id),
      }],
    },
});
```

Eu sugiro que você estude mais sobre [**WebAuthn**](https://webauthn.guide/) e as classes e métodos disponíveis para esta funcionalidade.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, mas quando tento fazer o import fica dizendo que: Module '"@angular/compiler"' has no exported member 'Credentials', tentei instalar o pacote e não consegui. Não sei se por causa disso o erro em get({password:true}) continua o mesmo: Argument of type '{ password: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CredentialRequestOptions'.

Comment: Veja se [isso](https://docs.amplication.com/tutorials/angular-todos/step-003/) te ajuda

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou estudar mais sobre WebAuthn e dar uma olhada no link do seu comentário anterior. Ai eu volto para dizer se consegui resolver ou não. Grato.